# How to add to variable using SSE2?

Tags: c++, sse2

### How to "add to" variable using SSE2?

I've recently been working with SSE2 in C++ to optimize a few math functions up, but ran into a problem when attempting to add to existing variables.

I have a function which intakes variables like so:

```
_m128d v1 {}; // Note: Global variable. 
_m128d v2 {}; // Note: Global variable. 

_mm_func& _mm_func::operator+=( const vector _mm0, const  vector _mm0 )
{
    v1 += _mm0.v1; // <-- Problem...

    v2 += _mm0.v2; // <-- Problem...

   return *this;
}
```

But I can't find the correct intrinsic name...

I know that `_mm_add_pd` would simply add the variables together, but I can't find any sources which could explain how I could add it to ( += ) the variable.

Source: [https://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~merz/intel_c10b/main_cls/mergedProjects/intref_cls/common/](https://www.cita.utoronto.ca/%7Emerz/intel_c10b/main_cls/mergedProjects/intref_cls/common/)

Comment: probably by assigning the result to the same variable again?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same. It ended up spitting out incorrect data for whatever reason. Still searching!

Comment: `_mm0` seems like a terrible variable name.  1. leading underscores in some contexts are reserved for use by the implementation.  2. MM0 is the name of a 64-bit MMX register, only usable for integer SIMD.  You clearly have an XMM register (when that variable is live in a register).

Comment: Also, it's generally a bad design to use `__m128d` global variables.  Using `_mm_load_pd` intrinsics or whatever on global arrays lets you keep the SIMD intrinsics contained to single function bodies, making it more modular and easier to port to other SIMD implementations like NEON.  (Use `alignas(16)` on such global arrays.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel's site: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/. Select SSE2, Artithemtic, and you'll get half a page of arithemtic instructions. You obviously want an `m128d` add, but the problem you have is that you need to specify how those 128 bits are organized. That could be anything from 16x8 to 2x64. `+=` can't be all those at the same time.

No, you can't have a 128 bits addition. SSE2 is vector math.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I was on Intel's intrinsics page earlier and couldn't find it. I just assumed it wasn't updated. Thank you!